# Can we default value in bean so even after WSDL generation the value will be retained?

Tags: wsdl, javabeans, java2wsdl

I have a property

```
private boolean submitRequests = true;
```

but when WSDL is generated the resulting bean does not retain the default "true" value. Is there a way or any annotation which can make it retain the default value?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer...

```
@XmlElement(defaultValue = "true")
public void setSubmitRequests(boolean submitRequests) {
    this.submitRequests = submitRequests;
}
```

this will do it